# emberjs new-router-V3/controller can't create or edit record using ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-router

In this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rxWzu/10/)**, I have **EmBlog.PostsNewRoute**  and **EmBlog.PostsEditRoute**. The routes contain events for 'save, cancel and destroy'.

When I create a new record, it only creates it in memory and never calls the store.commit() and in the console, it throws the error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'commit' of undefined**

When I try to edit, it throws thesame error but then the edit still happens only in memory.

The destroy action also fails.

When I call cancel, I get:

**Cannot read property 'defaultTransaction' of undefined**

Most of the code is in the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rxWzu/10/)**. The save and cancel events follow the pattern described by **[Yehuda here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1692)**:

```
    App.NewUserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function() {
         return App.User.createRecord();
      },

     events: {
         save: function(user) {
          this.get('store').commit();
         }
     }
   });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgrassotti/GLHWz/1/)! it is now working for create, edit and destroy use cases. See below for details on what I changed...

> When I create a new record, it only creates it in memory and never calls the store.commit() and in the console, it throws the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'commit' of undefined

original `PostNewRoute` failed because this.store is undefined. Also `this.content` would have been undefined.

```
save: function(post) {
  this.store.commit();
  this.content.addObserver('id', this, 'afterSave');
 },
```

Updated version calls commit on the post's transaction. Also using post.one callback to transition after record is created.

```
 save: function(post) {
   post.one('didCreate', this, function(){
     this.transitionTo('posts.show', post);
   });
   post.get('transaction').commit();
 },
```

Will update later with details on other updates...

> When I try to edit, it throws thesame error but then the edit still happens only in memory.
>
> The destroy action also fails.
>
> When I call cancel, I get: Cannot read property 'defaultTransaction' of undefined